# Python k8s client: is there a way to use wildcards on job-name query, when calling list_namespaced_pod?

Tags: python, kubernetes, client, kubectl

Getting all pods in a given namespace takes too long, so I'm trying somehow to reduce it. I don't know whether using such filtration may be faster or not, but I at least must try - if it's at all possible...

Tried stuff like: `label_selector='job-name=my-agent-*'` or `label_selector='job-name=my-agent-%'` and many other variations with no success. Full code:

```python
from kubernetes import config, client
from kubernetes.client import CoreV1Api, V1PodList

config.load_kube_config()
v1: CoreV1Api = client.CoreV1Api()
pods_list: V1PodList = v1.list_namespaced_pod(
    'dev-pool',
    label_selector='job-name=my-agent-*'
)
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: I believe the actual syntax is `label_selector='job-name'` indicating you wish to bring back pods that have such a label at all, then filter them client-side. If you have a discrete set of `my-agent-` values, [it supports `in` syntax](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors), too

Answer (score 0):

The use of wildcards is not documented. But, since you can pass a [series of label_selectors](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/1710), does the following approach work out for you?

```
# Example. Acquire job and agent names per your project requirements
selectors = [("job-name-1","my-agent-a"),("job-name-2","my-agent-b")]

# Job and agent names as string literal
# 'job_name_1=my_agent_a,job_name_2=my_agent_b'
label_selectors = ','.join('='.join(map(str, x)) for x in selectors)
```

Then:

```
...
config.load_kube_config()
v1: CoreV1Api = client.CoreV1Api()
pods_list: V1PodList = v1.list_namespaced_pod(
    'dev-pool',
    label_selector=label_selectors
)
```